# Django-Rest-Framework - nested serializers - Original exception text was: 'RelatedManager' object has no attribute 'field'

Tags: python, django-rest-framework

I cannot find a proper solution to make class Colors many=false, I got below code that works:

```
from django.conf import settings
from django.db import models


class Hall(models.Model):
    owner = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    status = models.CharField(max_length=255)

class Colors(models.Model):
    hall = models.ForeignKey(Hall, related_name="colors", on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    primary = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    secondary = models.CharField(max_length=255
```

```
from rest_framework import serializers

from halls.models import Colors, Hall

# from rest_framework.authtoken.models import Token


class ColorsSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Colors
        fields = ("primary", "secondary")


class HallSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    owner = serializers.HiddenField(default=serializers.CurrentUserDefault())
    colors = ColorsSerializer(many=True)

    class Meta:
        model = Hall
        fields = ("owner", "name", "status", "colors")

    def create(self, validated_data):
        colors = validated_data.pop("colors")
        hall = Hall.objects.create(**validated_data)
        for color in colors:
            Colors.objects.create(hall=hall, **color)
        return hall
```

when I send a request like it:

```
{
        "colors": [{"primary": "1", "secondary": "2"}],
        "status": "yes",
        "name": "some name",
}
```

So now I want to make it many=False but for some reason it doesn't work:

```
class HallSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    owner = serializers.HiddenField(default=serializers.CurrentUserDefault())
    colors = ColorsSerializer()

    class Meta:
        model = Hall
        fields = ("owner", "name", "status", "colors")

    def create(self, validated_data):
        colors = validated_data.pop("colors")
        hall = Hall.objects.create(**validated_data)
        Colors.objects.create(hall=hall, **colors)
        return hall
```

When sending below request:

```
{
        "colors": {"primary": "blue", "secondary": "green"},
        "status": "yes",
        "name": "DUZA 
}
```

I am getting below error:

*
AttributeError: Got AttributeError when attempting to get a value for field `primary` on serializer `ColorsSerializer`.The serializer field might be named incorrectly and not match any attribute or key on the `RelatedManager` instance.Original exception text was: 'RelatedManager' object has no attribute 'primary'.*

Comment: Could you share Color model as well ?

Comment: Done, my bad, missed that part of code when c/p

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way is to add `SerializerMethodField` instead of adding directly as `ColorsSerializer` because colors is a related name for `Hall`.

```
class HallSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    owner = serializers.HiddenField(default=serializers.CurrentUserDefault())
    colors = ColorsSerializer(write_only=True)
    colors_read = SerializerMethodField()
    class Meta:
        model = Hall
        fields = ("owner", "name", "status", "colors", "colors_read")
    
    def get_colors_read(self, obj):
        return ColorsSerializer(obj.colors.all(), many=True).data

    def create(self, validated_data):
        colors = validated_data.pop("colors")
        hall = Hall.objects.create(**validated_data)
        Colors.objects.create(hall=hall, **colors)
        return hall
```

Comment: If I change `write_only=False` I think it will stop working right? I need colors to be modifiable

Comment: Yes if you want to create Hall with colors you should `write_only=True`